# Hardy Weinberg Equilibrium problem

Tags: genetics, homework, hardy-weinberg

> In a small tribal population, the frequencies of two alleles A and a
>   at a particular locus were 0.3 and 0.7, respectively. However, not all
>   the individuals with genotype aa could live up to the reproductive age
>   and the relative fitness of this genotype was found to be 0.5. The
>   remaining genotypes had a relative fitness of 1. What is the expected
>   percentage of heterozygotes among newborns in the next generation?

My answer is : 37 % but the answer given 43.52 %

I did the following : First I assumed the population to be of 100 individuals and then I counted the no of individuals with respective genotypes. Then I assumed that each person leaves 1 offspring except the aa ones which leave 0.5 offsprings and then I calculated the new genotype frequency from this.

Comment: Are you saying that f(A)=0.3 and f(a)=0.7?

Comment: @fileunderwater yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is incorrect, because once you have the number of individuals surviving after the 50% mortality you can't just give them all one identical offspring, you have to mate them with one another.

However, I can't get the answer given, instead I get 47.9%

Here is my reasoning:

> f(**A**)=0.3
>
> f(**a**)=0.7

calculate genotype frequencies:

> **AA** = 0.3<sup>2</sup> = 0.09
>
> **aa** = 0.7<sup>2</sup> = 0.49
>
> **Aa** = 2 * 0.3 * 0.7 = 0.42

(these add to 1 as expected)

use 1000 individuals for nice round numbers

> number **AA** = 90
>
> number **aa** = 490
>
> number **Aa** = 420

Now apply 50% mortality in **aa** individuals:

> number **AA** => 90
>
> number **aa** => 245
>
> number **Aa** => 420

now calculate new allele frequencies in mating population:

> f(**A**) = (90 + 90 + 420)/1510 = 600/1510
>
> f(**a**) = (245 + 245 + 420)/1510 = 910/1510

calculate proportion of heterozygote offspring

> = 2 * f(**A**) * f(**a**)
>
> = (1200 * 910)/(1510 * 1510)
>
> = 0.479

I hope someone can see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I got 47.89% when only working with frequencies, so your answer seems right. My feeling was also that both answers were incorrect, therefore my comment to the question.

Comment: thanks @fileunderwater, I've been tearing my hair out over this! You should post your calculation - I expect it is more elegant than mine.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was getting as well, and I couldn't figure out how to get the 43.52%.

Answer (score 6):

This is basically the same solution as @AlanBoyd's answer, but since he asked me to, I will post my solution as well (also a reason to try out $\mathcal{MathJax}$ a bit more).

Assuming:

$f(A)=p=0.3, \\f(a)=q=0.7$

and the standard formulas:

$f(AA)=p^2\\
f(Aa)=2pq\\
f(aa)=q^2$

gives these genotypes in the parental generation (G1), before and after selection (using the fitness vector $w$):

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\text{genotype} & \text{freq G1} & w & \text{freq breed.pop} & \text{freq breed. rescaled}\\
\hline
AA & 0.09 & 1 & f(AA)\cdot w_{AA}=0.09 & 0.119\\
Aa & 0.42 & 1 & f(Aa)\cdot w_{Aa}=0.42 & 0.556 \\
aa & 0.49 & 0.5 & f(aa)\cdot w_{aa}=0.245 & 0.325\\
\text{sum} & 1 & & 0.755 & 1
\end{array}
$$

The genotype frequencies in the breeding population (rescaled so that they sum to one) are then used to calculate allele frequencies as:

$$f(A)=f(AA)+\frac{f(Aa)}{2} = 0.397\\
f(a)=f(aa)+\frac{f(Aa)}{2} = 0.603$$

These are then used to calculate the genotype frequencies in the next generation (G2), using the same HW-equations as in the beginning:

$$\begin{align}
f(AA)&=0.397^2=0.158 \\
f(Aa)&=2\cdot0.397\cdot0.603=0.479 \\
f(aa)&=0.603^2=0.363 \\
\end{align}
$$

I do not understand where the given answer $f(Aa)=0.435$ is coming from.